# prestashop 1.7 - simple module does'nt work

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I created simple module following instructions in this documentation chapter:

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Creating+a+first+module

This is my file /modules/steel/steel.php:

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
exit;

class Steel extends Module
{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->name = 'steel';
    $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
    $this->version = '1.0.0';
    $this->author = 'Firstname Lastname';
    $this->need_instance = 0;
    $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);

parent::__construct();

$this->displayName = 'xxx';
$this->description = 'desc';
$this->confirmUninstall = 'deinstall?';
}

public function install()
{
    return false;
  return true;
}

public function uninstall()
{
  if (!parent::uninstall())
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

For some reason it doesnt show up in modules list so i can install it. WHen i make it into zip file and try to install it using "upload modile" function, it shows "Installation of module steel failed. The module is invalid and cannot be loaded.".

Comment: Class is missing closing brace and `install()` method always returns false, you're not calling it's parent method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class Steel extends Module
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'steel';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Firstname Lastname';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = 'xxx';
        $this->description = 'desc';
        $this->confirmUninstall = 'deinstall?';
    }

    public function install()
    {
        return parent::install();
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        return parent::uninstall();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well if you're just calling parent methods in install and uninstall methods then you don't need them:)